# only manipulating content inside of {} in ts

Tags: javascript, typescript

```js
  const toReplace = [
    { key: "{user1}", value: member.user.toString() },
    { key: "{user2}", value: invite.inviter.toString() },
  ];
  toReplace.forEach((r) => {
    welcomeFormat = welcomeFormat.toLowerCase().replace(r.key.toLowerCase(), String(r.value));
  });
```

Hey guys. Currently I'm trying to replace a specific string with lowercase, to reduce the chance of userinput error.

However, the following code replacing the WHOLE message tolowercase. How would i go about only replacing contents inside of `{}` to lowercase?

Comment: Do you know that the first and last character are gonna be braces?

Comment: No, it will be random every time.

Comment: Will there be multiple pairs or only single pair?

Comment: There will be multiple, or single. Depends what the user wants. (could be single, could be both)

Comment: So what you have to do is find all such instances between these 2 braces and manipulate/replace them. Are you sure they are only going to exist in pairs. Because user can input anything.

Comment: the user can put anything they like, so it could be {user1} and {user2} or just {user2}

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/233674/discussion-between-lolnoob-lolnooa-and-tushar-shahi).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is better to do it with `map` (not `forEach`).

```js
const toReplace = [
    { key: "{user1}", value: member.user.toString() },
    { key: "{user2}", value: invite.inviter.toString() },
  ];

const newToReplace = toReplace.map((r) => {
    return {
        ...r,
        key: r.key.toLowerCase(),
    };
});
```

this way, you can keep both arrays but if you want to replace the original array with the new one, you can name it `toReplace` to replace it with the new one.